# LaTeX: Table of contents

Tags: latex

I am trying to generate a table of contents using latex and I succeeded but I want to edit it at which the whole table is written in capital as in the figure attached [image: Table of contents]

I tried this code:

```
%To make the sections in uppercase
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}% Sections use UPPERCASE in ToC
\makeatother
```

But it produced an error.

Is there any alternative to do that? Your help is appreciated

Comment: Please make a [mre] that shows us which class you use

Comment: Duplicate: [Table of contents manipulation - LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69109830/table-of-contents-manipulation-latex)